# Entity framework generates inefficient SQL

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-core

I wonder why is Entity framework generating such an inefficient SQL query. In my code I expected the WHERE to act upon the INCLUDE:

```
db.Employment.Where(x => x.Active).Include(x => x.Employee).Where(x => x.Employee.UserID == UserID)
```

but I ended up with a double SQL JOIN:

```
SELECT [x].[ID], [x].[Active], [x].[CurrencyID], [x].[DepartmentID], [x].[EmplEnd], [x].[EmplStart], [x].[EmployeeID], [x].[HolidayGroupID], [x].[HourlyCost], [x].[JobTitle], [x].[ManagerID], [x].[WorkScheduleGroupID], [e].[ID], [e].[Active], [e].[Address], [e].[BirthDate], [e].[CitizenshipID], [e].[City], [e].[CountryID], [e].[Email], [e].[FirstName], [e].[Gender], [e].[LastName], [e].[Note], [e].[Phone], [e].[PostalCode], [e].[TaxNumber], [e].[UserID]
FROM [Employment] AS [x]
INNER JOIN [Employee] AS [x.Employee] ON [x].[EmployeeID] = [x.Employee].[ID]
INNER JOIN [Employee] AS [e] ON [x].[EmployeeID] = [e].[ID]
WHERE ([x].[Active] = 1) AND ([x.Employee].[UserID] = @__UserID_0)
```

I found out that this query will create better SQL:

```
db.Employment.Where(x => x.Active).Where(x => x.Employee.UserID == UserID)

SELECT [x].[ID], [x].[Active], [x].[CurrencyID], [x].[DepartmentID], [x].[EmplEnd], [x].[EmplStart], [x].[EmployeeID], [x].[HolidayGroupID], [x].[HourlyCost], [x].[JobTitle], [x].[ManagerID], [x].[WorkScheduleGroupID]
FROM [Employment] AS [x]
INNER JOIN [Employee] AS [x.Employee] ON [x].[EmployeeID] = [x.Employee].[ID]
WHERE ([x].[Active] = 1) AND ([x.Employee].[UserID] = @__UserID_0)
```

However, the problem here that referenced entities are not retrieved from the DB.

Why don't two codes produce same SQLs?

Comment: First you should compare their query plans - they might be identical.

Comment: I don't see the point here, I use EF as an layer of abstraction over SQL, if I have to go all the way down to the query plan I might be better off writing SQL myself, instead of letting EF do it.

Comment: You can combine both the conditions in one where method using && operator after applying Include.  That should generate different query.

Comment: Using an obfuscation layer like entityframework does _not_ relieve you from understanding SQL and being able to tune SQL statements.

Comment: What I'm getting at is..... use the query plan to work out whether the queries _really are different_ - they probably aren't

Comment: To put it another way: if the query plans are identical between these two queries (they most likely are), then _functionally_, and _performance-wise_ they are identical. One has more code but what do you care since it's autogenerated? EF is the best SQL code generator I've seen so far

Comment: I'm currently using SQL server, but due to pricing I might use another DB in the future (as long as it's supported by EF, of course). So I have to trust that EF is doing a good job and that generated SQL will be optimized for any decent DB engine, at least for simple JOIN cases like this one. Nevertheless I examined the DB execution plans for both cases and they are different, 6 vs 4 steps, so unless there's something I'm missing here, the EF generated code in this case is not good enough.

Comment: What version of EF are you using? I'm asking because there is a big difference between different EF versions, especially in EF Core which seem to be used here (according to the generated SQL).

Comment: Yes, it's the latest EF Core (with ASP .Net Core).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQL is different because the statments are different.

Entity Framework does produce inefficient TSQL, it always has. By abstracting the subtleties that are necessary for SQL with good performance and replacing them with "belt and braces" **nearly** always work alternatives you sacrafice performance for utility.

If you need good performance, write the SQL yourself. [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) works well for me. You can't realistically expect a "one size fits all" solution to come up with the best code for your specific situation. You can do this across the board or just where you need to.

Unless you have high volume or specific performance requirements get on with it and use whatever you find easiest. If you need to tune your queries to your database you are going to have learn the details of your database engine and implement the queries yourself. If you are expecting the next iteration of Entity Framework to be the magic bullet that allows you fast, efficient SQL data access with minimal knowledge, good luck.

P.S.

Off-topic but, [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) probably isn't the answer either, is just a different class of database.

Comment: Adding to this that SQL text is different, but the query plan can be / probably is the same in your context. +1 for EF always producing inefficient SQL. You can always monitor most costly queries and remove EF from that area switching to calling sprocs using Dapper or smth similar. NoSql isn't the answer in your scenario.

Comment: No, the query plan is not the same, that's the problem. However, I understood that I can't trust EF to generate good SQL for even a litle bit more complex queries, like the displayed JOIN.

Comment: @Marko I understand your disappointment. If the database model included information about indicies, data statistics and more constraints it could theoretically make a more efficient and safe query. However, I see two drawbacks, its a lot of work that would be tightly coupled to this version of SQL Server and its the kind of physical detail an ORM is trying to "protect" non-database developers from.